# When gets transaction result visible?

Tags: postgresql, transaction

I have a transaction that inserts a row into table, and then, in the JTA Synchronization afterCommit (on success) fires an event. The event can be later read in another thread and when this happens this thread fetches the record from the database.

The test show a race condition, though: in some cases the inserted row is not visible to the fetching thread yet. I was hoping that this would get fixed with `serializable` isolation level but it is not.

Is this something that could be expected? I would assume that with TX commit the TX would be **fully** flushed, even to a query happening on a different connection. Is there anything I could do to not present stale results?

This is PostgreSQL 12 (running in a container). Happens on both my machine and in CI.

Comment: "*even to a query happening on a different connection*" - _while_ the query is running it will never see _any_ changes to the database (not even committed changes). Wether it sees changes after that, depends on the isolation level and if it's part of a bigger transaction

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't have any nested transactions. It's ofc correct that the TX is not visible until it commits, but although the query happens after the TX commit it does not see the after-state. It is not wrong from the isolation POV but the whole system (that extends beyond DB, the message is sent within app) is not causally in sync, and I am looking for something to make that happen.

Comment: It should be visible immediately unless you are reading from a replica.  Your code is probably wrong, but without seeing the code, what can we say?